# xdebug.remote_connect_back in Debian Squeeze not working

Tags: php, netbeans, debian, xdebug

I'm trying to setup remote debugging on my server running Debian squeeze.
I got it working by setting the IP of the host in xdebug-config. But I want to enable debug sessions from all hosts. This should be possible by setting

```
 xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
```

However if I add that line, the debugger doesn't connect back anymore (trying with Netbeans). This should be supported by the xdebug coming with Debian Squeeze (2.1.0-1).

That's my /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini:

```
    zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
    ; Remote settings
    xdebug.remote_autostart=off
    xdebug.remote_enable=on
    xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
    xdebug.remote_mode=req
    ; overrides the host setting, but seems to not work
    ; xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
    xdebug.remote_host=192.168.23.22
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

That way it works. If xdebug.remote_connect_back=on is uncommented it stops working. Why?

Comment: Are you using any proxy?

Comment: no. no proxy, no firewall. I tried to connect to port 9000 of my host from the server with telnet and it succeeded.